# Docker swarm - Port not accessible

Tags: docker, nginx, docker-swarm

I am trying out some things with docker and docker swarm and currently I am running into a problem.

If I create a container with:
*`docker run -d --name my_nginx -p 8080:80 nginx`*
everythings went fine, I am able to access this port.

If I try to create a service with docker swarm (container was removed before) I am not able to open that port:
*`docker service create -d --name my_service_nginx --replicas=1 -p 8080:80 nginx`*

It seems that the service does not create a portmapping.

```
CONTAINER ID   IMAGE          COMMAND                  CREATED         STATUS         PORTS     NAMES
d3417b80036c   nginx:latest   "/docker-entrypoint.…"   6 minutes ago   Up 6 minutes   80/tcp    my_service.1.1l3fwcct1m9hoallkn0g9qwpd
```

Do you have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Best regards
Jan

Comment: *"I am not able to open that port"* – what do you mean here exactly? I just tried with `curl` and I got the exact same result both times.

Comment: If I do a curl like this:
curl localhost:8080

I get the following error:
curl: (7) Failed to connect to localhost port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: Which OS do you use?

Comment: Did a little bit of testing meanwhile...
It seems that it is related to my host which is an LXC-Container in proxmox.
If I run that service in a regular debian vm the service is reachable.

Comment: The LXC container was an Ubuntu 20.04, the debian vm is debian 11.

Answer (score 0):

Launching a Docker swarm on the LXC is not possible:

[Docker swarm get access from outside network](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74987323/docker-swarm-get-access-from-outside-network)

Answer (score 0):

I am able to access Docker swarm on the `Proxmox LXC` by enabling `ip_forward` for *ingress_sbox* namespace.

`nsenter --net=/run/docker/netns/ingress_sbox sysctl -w net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`